# SWT Text Box Border Color

Tags: text, swt, widget

How to customize SWT  Text Box Border color? 
Is there any API to modify the border color of SWT widgets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no such API for changing the border color of a text. Alternatively you can attach a paint listener to the widget and try to paint the border by yourself with a different color.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for responding, Can I have your number please.Can u write a sample text Box, so that it will help me to do that.Through out our project, all text boxes are in some default color and due to back ground color, text boxes are not visible properly,Can u tell me how that can be achieved,In IBM Lotus and other RAP/RCP applications, we can see , text boxes with different borders, How do they achieve that

Comment: Sir,Please, can I have your number, I ma vineel from Pune, i have two other doubts in RCP applications,I am doing my final year